# Arrangements of sets of k positions in a n-competitors race

Tags: java, algorithm, function, math, set

this is a copy of my post on mathexchange.com.

Let ***E(n)*** be the set of all possible **ending arrangements** of a race of ***n*** **competitors**.

Obviously, because it's a race, each one of the ***n*** competitors wants to win.
Hence, the order of the arrangements **does** matter.
Let us also say that if two competitors end with the same result of time, they win the same spot.

For example, ***E(3)*** contains the following sets of arrangements:

**{(1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,2,1), (1,2,2), (1,2,3), (1,3,2), (2,1,1), (2,1,2),(2,1,3), (2,2,1), (2,3,1), (3,1,2), (3,2,1)}.**

Needless to say, for example, that the arrangement **(1,3,3)** is invalid, because the two competitors that **supposedly** ended in the third place, **actually** ended in the second place. So the above arrangement **"transfers"** to **(1,2,2).**

Define ***k*** to be the number of **distinct** **positions** of the competitors in a subset of ***E(n).*** 
We have for example:

**(1,1,1) -------> k = 1**

**(1,2,1) -------> k = 2**

**(1,2,3,2) -------> k = 3**

**(1,2,1,5,4,4,3) -------> k = 5**

**Finally**, let ***M(n,k)*** be the **number of subsets** of ***E(n)*** in which the competitors ended in **exactly** ***k*** distinct positions.

We get, for example,***M(3,3) = M(3,2) = 6*** and ***M(3,1) = 1***.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Thus far is the question

It's a problem I came up with solely by myself. After some time of thought I came up with the following recursive formula for ***|E(n)|:*** 
**(Don't continue reading if you want to derive a formula yourself!)**

***|E(n)|*** = **sum from l=1 to n of C(n,l)*|E(n-l)|** **where** **|E(0)| = 1**

And the code in Java for this function, using the BigInteger class:

```
public static BigInteger E (int n)
{
    if (!Ens[n].equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
        return Ens[n];
    else
    {
        BigInteger ends=BigInteger.ZERO;
        for (int l=1;l<=n;l++)
            ends=ends.add(factorials[n].divide(factorials[l].multiply(factorials[n-l])).multiply(E(n-l)));
        Ens[n]=ends;
        return ends;
    }
}
```

The **factorials** array is an array of precalculated factorials for faster binomial coefficients calculations.

The **Ens** array is an array of the memoized/cached ***E(n)*** values which really quickens the calculating, due to the need of repeatedly calculating certain ***E(n)*** values.

The logic behind this recurrence relation is that **l** symbolizes how many "first" spots we have. For each **l**, the binomial coefficient **C(n,l)** symbolizes in how many ways we can pick **l** first-placers out of the **n** competitors. Once we have chosen them, we to need to figure out in how many ways we can arrange the **n-l** competitors we have left, which is just **|E(n-l)|**.
I get the following:

**|E(3)| = 13**

**|E(5)| = 541**

**|E(10)| = 102247563**

**|E(100)| mod 1 000 000 007 = 619182829 -------> 20 ms.**

**And |E(1000)| mod 1 000 000 007 = 581423957 -------> 39 sec.**

I figured out that ***|E(n)|*** can also be visualized as the number of sets to which the following applies:

For every **i = 1, 2, 3 ... n**, every **i-tuple** subset of the original set has GCD (greatest common divisor) of all of its elements equal to 1.
But I'm not 100% sure about this because I was not able to compute this approach for large **n**.
However, even with precalculating factorials and memoizing the **E(n)'s**, the calculating times for higher **n's** grow very fast.
Is anyone capable of verifying the above formula and values?
Can anyone derive a better, faster formula? Perhaps with generating functions?

As for ***M(n,k)***.. I'm totally clueless. I absolutely have no idea how to calculate it, and therefore I couldn't post any meaningful data points. 
Perhaps it's **P(n,k) = n!/(n-k)!.**
Can anyone figure out a formula for ***M(n,k)***?

I have no idea which function is harder to compute, either ***E(n)*** or ***M(n,k)***, but helping me with either of them will be very much appreciable.

I want the solutions to be generic as well as work efficiently even for large **n's**. Exhaustive search is not what I'm looking for, unfortunately. 
What I am looking for is solutions based purely on combinatorial approach and efficient formulas.

I hope I was clear enough with the wording and what I ask for throughout my post. By the way, I can program using Java. I also know Mathematica pretty decently :) .

Thanks a lot in advance,

Matan.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000670

Comment: Wow, even almost the same wording.. Exactly the same formula too. 
What about M(n,k)? Do you know anything about it? @DavidEisenstat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E(n) are the [Fubini numbers](https://oeis.org/A000670). M(n, k) = S(n, k) * k!, where S(n, k) is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), because S(n, k) is the number of different placing partitions, and k! is the number of ways to rank them.

Comment: Thank you so much! =) I have no idea how you knew all of this.. Really amazing.

Comment: @Matan Some combination of OEIS search (really useful if you're playing with integer sequences) and experience.